# Is it possible to customize the colors of RockScroll's variable syntax highlighting?

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

As some of you know the RockScroll Visual Studio plugin is pretty darn awesome.  It turns your scrollbar into a mini preview of your code and offers the Eclipse like functionality of highlighting any word that you doubleclick in your code.

The problem is the author of RockScroll chose a color that is VERY difficult to see and almost defeats the purpose of such a cool and very useful feature.

So my question is.  Is it possible to customize the color or specify your own somehow?

Stay tuned because I answered my own question and found a way!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set it by going to

Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > rockscroll

Rockscroll.dll is version 2.1.0.0 (05/09/2008)

Comment: This option exists, but does not appear to have any effect here. Using Rockscroll 2.1 on Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a way to accomplish this by hex-editing the rockscroll .dll

By default RockScroll uses a very light purple, bluish color: F5E7FE.

1. Open up your favorite HexEditor.
2. Open the RockScroll.dll in your Program Files\RockScroll directory (back it up first!)
3. Search for the color specified above and remember to search using the proper byte-order.
4. I happened to find that color sequence on line: 00006FDC
5. Enter a new color of choice...I chose a more prominent yellow/gold color: E8E8FF
6. Save the file and close it then restart Visual Studio and if you managed to do this correctly Visual Studio will start with no complaints.
7. Open up some code and double click a word...you should have the new color available immediately.

Cheers!

Disclaimer: This is considered a hack so do this at your own risk!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [MetalScroll](http://code.google.com/p/metalscroll/) instead!

It does everything and more that RockScroll does and is easily configurable.

Comment: With the small restriction that the highlight color is about the only color that is NOT configurable... => FAIL